# Dialogflow - Can 1 follow-up intent has more than 1 parent

Tags: dialogflow-es

Can Follow-up intent has more than 1 parent?

For example, my program will be like

```
from(A) 

if(A.response == yes){

go_to_intent(B)

go_to_intent(C) //A-->B-->C

}

else

go_to_intent_(C) //A-->C
```

which can be seen that both B and A are the possible parents of C.

So how to set C as the follow-up intent of both A and B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - no. You're not supposed to "go to" Intents - Intents represent user inputs under different conditions.

So Using your example, the user has said or done something that matches Intent A. As a response, your agent asks a question.

- If they answer "yes", then it should match Intent B.
- If not, then it will match Intent C.

Now... what you do in your webhook fulfillment in Intents A, B, and C is a completely different story. You're allowed to call the same functions for B and C and just return different messages from each.

Intents aren't about what your agent does - it is about what your *user* does.

**Update**

Based on your example in the comments, I want to repeat - don't think of Intents as what your agent is saying, think of it as what the user is saying or doing.

Based on this, I would rephrase your Intents this way:

- When the user starts the action, this triggers Intent A. In the handler for Intent A:

  - Set the context "ask-city"
  - Send the message "Do you want to provide the city?"
- When the context "ask-city" is active, and the user says "yes", trigger Intent B. In the handler for Intent B:

  - Clear the context "ask-city"
  - Set the context "prompt-city"
  - Send the message "What city?"
- When the context "ask-city" is active, the user may also just reply with the city, so trigger Intent B1. In the handler for Intent B1:

  - Clear the context "ask-city"
  - Save the city information
  - Set the context "prompt-gender"
  - Send the message "What is your gender?"
- When the context "ask-city" is active, the user may reply "no", so trigger Intent C. In the handler for Intent C:

  - Clear the context "ask-city"
  - Save that there is no city information
  - Set the context "prompt-gender"
  - Send the message "What is your gender?"
- When the context "prompt-city" is active, and the user says a city name, trigger Intent C1. In the handler for Intent C1:

  - Clear the context "prompt-city"
  - Save the city information
  - Set the context "prompt-gender"
  - Send the message "What is your gender?"

You notice that Intents B1, C, and C1 all have very similar, but not identical, fulfillments. So in your webhook, they can all essentially call the same (or similar) code. But you notice that they're triggered under slightly different conditions, so each one needs a different Dialogflow Intent.

I added Intent B1 because this may very well be how the user responds to you. In a conversational UI, we're not presenting them with a phone menu - they can respond as if they were responding to another human asking the same question.

Also keep in mind that there may be other Intents that you want to build that are handled differently in each state. For example, when the "ask-city" context is valid, if the user says something besides "yes", "no", or a city, you may want to clarify what you're asking.

Also note that none of these are, technically, Followup Intents. Followup Intents are just some visual coating around Contexts. You never need to use a Followup Intent - they just make some, very specific, things better organized. In your case - they also cause problems. If all you accept in a followup is "yes" and "no", then the user saying other things aren't allowed and you end up with a much more stilted conversation. The important part about each case isn't if they're followups or not - they're the ability to set an output context and that Intents will only be triggered on those contexts being specified as input contexts.

Comment: My intent A is "do you want to input your information about your city?".            

Intent b, after the user answers "yes", is "please named your city".           


Intent c, after the user answers "no" or after the user named user's city in intent b, is "please identify your own sex", which does not correspond to B or A.        

So I want to ask how can intent B send to intent C??

Comment: Thanks for the clear example. That means if I have around 5 cases like this, I have to create around 32 intents, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure where you get "32 intents" from. I count 4 Intents per question that can be asked, and fewer if you don't want to handle yes/no (which you should avoid if you can, because the conversation is awkward). You can use fewer if you use more generic Intents and keep track of the state of the conversation and what the user is responding to. Remember - think in terms of what the user is saying, not what you're saying.

Comment: I thought all of these have to be "follow-up intents". so that means if each we have 5 question, each question can be answer yes,no.

All the possible cases will be (Y,Y,Y,Y,Y), (Y,Y,Y,Y,N).... and so on until (N,N,N,N,N) which is 32 cases --> 32 intent to handle each cases...

Not sure if I understand it right or not.

Comment: Nope. Added another paragraph to, hopefully, clarify. It isn't about Followup Intents - it is all about Contexts.